# Delphi 10.1 Berlin default style sheet (Text, not binary)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

If I right click on a firemonkey control, i can choose to edit either custom or default style of control and then save to a file (.style). But that just gives me the style for that particular control (and then it really doesn't display everything, e.g. it doesn't show CheckBoxStyle for the TCheckColumn of the TGrid control).

How can i get a "text" version of the entire default style sheet?

thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using an answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32507249/how-can-i-set-the-default-system-style-in-delphi-10-seattle)
i was able to get the file created changing the style format from TStyleFormat.Binary to TStyleFormat.Text

```
procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
 Default_Style_Block_Pointer:  TFileStream;
begin
 Default_Style_Block_Pointer:=TFileStream.Create('default.StyleBook',fmCreate or fmOpenWrite or fmShareDenyWrite);
  TStyleStreaming.SaveToStream(TStyleManager.ActiveStyle(Self),Default_Style_Block_Pointer,TStyleFormat.Text);

end;
```